# I want to lock my computer from ssh using psshutdown but it isn't working :/

Tags: windows-10, ssh, remote-shutdown

I want to lock my computer from ssh using psshutdown but it isn't working :/
I tried everything i found on internet but I ended with error

```
C:\Users\amade>psshutdown -l

PsShutdown v2.52 - Shutdown, logoff and power manage local and remote systems
Copyright (C) 1999-2006 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

Error locking local system:
Access is denied.
```

Comment: Are you running the executable as an elevated user?  Have you tried to specify the username and password of an Administrator?  The error you received is indicating the user that your using does NOT have the required permission.

Comment: @Ramhound It doesn't work for me either (running as admin on Windows7). The command runs and claims the computer is locked but it isn't

Comment: @Ramhound Yeah, I tried

Comment: @DavidPostill - the shutdown command doesn't do user authentication.  So alternative [methods](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8e32fbe2-1195-4d8e-925c-f012e5814315/psshutdown-access-is-denied?forum=pstools) have to be used.

Answer (score 1):

> - Locking PC: `psexec -s -i 1 \\DESKTOP-TRISK "C:\Windows\System32\psshutdown.exe" -l -t 0`. Change DESKTOP-TRISK to your desktop name -> open cmd and type in "hostname",
>   should display your current desktop name.
> - Sleeping PC: `psshutdown -d -t 0`
> - Shutdown PC: `psshutdown -f -t 0`

Credits to [u/Trisks](https://old.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/s0e3pm/help_locking_my_pc_over_ssh/ido0ldp/) for finding this solution